# Comparing list item values to other items in other list in Python

Tags: python, plone, zope

I want to compare the values in one list to the values in a second list and return all those that are in the first list but not in the second i.e.

```
list1 = ['one','two','three','four','five']
list2 = ['one','two','four']
```

would return 'three' and 'five'.

I have only a little experience with python, so this may turn out to be a ridiculous and stupid way to attempt to solve it, but this what I have done so far:

```
def unusedCategories(self):
    unused = []
    for category in self.catList:
        if category != used in self.usedList:
            unused.append(category)
    return unused
```

However this throws an error 'iteration over non-sequence', which I gather to mean that one or both 'lists' aren't actually lists (the raw output for both is in the same format as my first example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use sets to get the difference between the lists:

```
>>> list1 = ['one','two','three','four','five']
>>> list2 = ['one','two','four']
>>> set(list1) - set(list2)
set(['five', 'three'])
```

Comment: This works fine for me, plus it's simple, so I think I'll stick with this one for now, thanks everyone for your speedy and helpful input

Comment: @chrism: are you implying that anything else posted here is complex?

Comment: no, but perhaps I'm too simple to figure out why my implementations of the other things I tried first didn't work?

Comment: I know this is old, but does anyone else have the problem of `set` turning the item strings into Unicode?

Answer (score 8):

`set(list1).difference(set(list2))`

Answer (score 1):

with [`set.difference`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference):

```
>>> list1 = ['one','two','three','four','five']
>>> list2 = ['one','two','four']
>>> set(list1).difference(list2)
{'five', 'three'}
```

you can skip conversion of `list2` to set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sets or a list comprehension:

```
unused = [i for i in list1 if i not in list2]
```

Comment: This works when I directly input sample lists in, but doesn't when I try to use my automatic lists (e.g. list1 = self.catList) - again with the iteration over non-sequence error, does this mean self.catList isn't really providing a list?

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here are correct.  I would use list comprehension if the lists are short;  sets will be more efficient.  In exploring why your code doesn't work, I don't get the error.  (It doesn't work, but that's a different issue).

```
>>> list1 = ['a','b','c']
>>> list2 = ['a','b','d']
>>> [c for c in list1 if not c in list2]
['c']
>>> set(list1).difference(set(list2))
set(['c'])
>>> L = list()
>>> for c in list1:
...     if c != L in list2:
...         L.append(c)
... 
>>> L
[]
```

The problem is that the `if` statement makes no sense.
Hope this helps.